# How to get micro SD Card ID in J2ME?

Tags: java-me, sd-card

I am in need of retreiving the SD Card ID(micro) thro J2ME.

Comment: Use a search engine for generic questions about a subject.  When you have specific problems with an attempted solution, post that attempt on SO and then ask for help. Please send me the code is not the purpose of SO, getting help when you're lost/in trouble is where it is most useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Java ME API for getting this information. On Nokia Series 60, you might be able to do it from a native application.
Thanks